# Removing space after title

Tags: spacing, titles, remove

I am fairly new to Latex and I am trying to remove the space between the title and my first section heading.

I currently have these commands:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article} \usepackage[tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1.25in,rmargin=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titling}
\setlength{\droptitle}{-5em}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\title{\textbf{\textit{\underline{Assistive Electronic Device Solutions in Urology}}}}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction and Scope}\label{sec:intro}

example text


\end{document}
```

Which looks like:

[image]

How can I remove the space between the title and section 1?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add the complete code of your small document, from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`. Without knowing the document class and major settings in the preamble we cannot answer your question.

Comment: \documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}    % use "amsart" instead of "article" for AMSLaTeX format
            
       % gives same margins as word      
\usepackage[tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1.25in,rmargin=1.25in]{geometry} 


%\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}    
\usepackage{graphicx}   
         
\usepackage{titling}           
\setlength{\droptitle}{-5em}   
       
\usepackage{amssymb}

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article} \usepackage[tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1.25in,rmargin=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titling}
\setlength{\droptitle}{-5em}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\title{\textbf{\textit{\underline{Assistive Electronic Device Solutions in Urology}}}}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

%%%%%%%% added this
\vspace{-1.5in} % adjust the length to suit your aesthetic 

\section{Introduction and Scope}\label{sec:intro}

example text


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to redefine `\@maketitle`. In the following code the parts related to author and date have been commented out and the desired (although ugly) formatting applied to `\@title`. Also all vertical spaces have been removed and only the vertical space due to `center` will remain.

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1.25in,rmargin=1.25in]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
%  \vskip 2em%
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\LARGE \bfseries\itshape\underline{\@title}\par}% <-- changed
%    \vskip 1.5em%
%    {\large
%      \lineskip .5em%
%      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
%        \@author
%      \end{tabular}\par}%
%    \vskip 1em%
%    {\large \@date}%
  \end{center}%
  \par
%  \vskip 1.5em
}
\makeatother

\title{Assistive Electronic Device Solutions in Urology}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction and Scope}\label{sec:intro}

example text

\end{document}
```

[image]